# laravel 4 mockery mock model relationships

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, mocking, laravel-4, mockery

say I have two models that extend from `Eloquent` and they relate to each other.  Can I mock the relationship?

ie:

```
class Track extends Eloquent {
    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Course');
    }
}

class Course extends Eloquent {
    public function track()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Track');
    }
}
```

in MyTest, I want to create a mock of course, and return an instance of track, **by calling the track property, not the track instance** (*I don't want the query builder*)

```
use \Mockery as m;

class MyTest extends TestCase {
    public function setUp()
    {
        $track = new Track(array('title' => 'foo'));
        $course = m::mock('Course[track]', array('track' => $track));

        $track = $course->track  // <-- This should return my track object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since track is a property and not a method, when creating the mock you will need to override the `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` methods of the model. Below is a solution that will let you set up an expectation for the property you're looking for:

```
$track = new Track(array('title' => 'foo'));
$course = m::mock('Course[setAttribute,getAttribute]');
// You don't really care what's returned from setAttribute
$course->shouldReceive('setAttribute');
// But tell getAttribute to return $track whenever 'track' is passed in
$course->shouldReceive('getAttribute')->with('track')->andReturn($track);
```

You don't need to specify the `track` method when mocking the `Course` object, unless you are also wanting to test code that relies on the query builder.  If this is the case, then you can mock the `track` method like this:

```
// This is just a bare mock object that will return your track back
// whenever you ask for anything. Replace 'get' with whatever method 
// your code uses to access the relationship (e.g. 'first')
$relationship = m::mock();
$relationship->shouldReceive('get')->andReturn([ $track ]);

$course = m::mock('Course[track]');
$course->shouldReceive('track')->andReturn($relationship);
```