# Mocking a function using Laravel and PHPUnit

Tags: database, model-view-controller, laravel-4, phpunit, mockery

I am using Laravel for some projects, and I am trying to create a test for a function. Here is the function in the my controller:

```
 public function showThoseThings()
  {
    return parent::httpRequest(
        function ($context) {
            $context->results['item'] = $this->object->findOrFail(list_id)->getElements;
        }
    );
  }
```

the "getElements()" function is defined in the model as follow:

```
public function getElements()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'things',
            'thing_to_list',
            'list_id',
            'thing_id'
        )
                ->withPivot('position')
                ->orderBy('thing_to_list.position');
    }
```

Basically in the backend there are three tables a list table that is a collection of things, then there is a things table that contains multiple things associated to a list then we have the pivot table. How can I mock this with Laravel. Here is what I have been doing:

```
public function testShowThoseTHingsSuccess()
{
    $this->mock->shouldReceive('findOrFail')->with(1)->andReturn($this->mock);
    $this->mock->shouldReceive('getElements')->once()->andReturn($this->mock);

   $response = $this->call('GET', 'workingURI');
    var_dump($response);
     $this->assertTrue($response->isOk());
```

But when running phpunit in the command line I am getting:

> "Unknown Error","message":"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user... Fails asserting that false is true".

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21688413/1903366

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your `$this->mock->..` method is doing but apparently not mocking the model you want. 
Because the error states that something tries to access the database and doesn't have correct credentials.

Also the lines:

```
$this->mock->shouldReceive('findOrFail')->with(1)->andReturn($this->mock);
$this->mock->shouldReceive('getElements')->once()->andReturn($this->mock);
```

Makes no sense to me, You create a mock of a model and when the methods `findOrFail` or `getElements` are triggered you return the same object.. The method `getElements` states to me that there should be returned some array with models..

**Some more info when you want to use a testing database**

When you run unit test with laravel and uses the base test class, then Laravel sets the `environment` to `testing`. Make sure that you have the right database configuration set for this environment.

You can use I.E. the following configuration to create a database in memory for testing:

```
// app/config/testing/database.php

<?php

return array(

    'default' => 'sqlite',

    'connections' => array(
        'sqlite' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            'prefix'   => ''
        ),
    )
);
```

Don't forget to migrate your DB schema before testing, place the following line in the `public function setUp()` of the base test class.

```
Artisan::call('migrate');
```

More info about simulating the databse: [NetTuts testing laravel models](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-like-a-boss-in-laravel-models--net-30087)

Comment: Aha, I wrote in a comment above (now deleted) that `app/config/testing/database.php` should be `config/testing/database.php`, but having done some more reading I've found that your information is correct for Laravel 4. Laravel 5 moved the config folder from `app/config/` to `config/`, but the cascading env-specific configuration no longer works in L5, from what I can tell. However, there are third-party packages that can get this to work.